# Workflow 2013 Copy Document Issue

Tags: workflow, document-library, workflow-activity

I have a document review workflow that, at one stage, copies the document over to another library.  Recently, I started having a problem where, when it gets to the copy document action, the workflow goes to suspended and will not move on.  The document is not copied.

This is the error that is showing up next to the 'Suspended' workflow status:

> Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the
>   workflow instance. Exception details: System.ArgumentNullException:
>   Value cannot be null. Parameter name: Input at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context) at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you checked your page  has been checked in ? and check you have any item level permission .At last check al the mandatory fields are entered and then form has been saved.

Comment: This is what I found thanks to MaartenSundmanSlalom Consulting:  253 characters from the end of the FQDN, not a bug, by design and same behavior exists in Windows too :)